# Android Expandable List View Child Focus

Tags: android, focus, expandablelistview

I have an expandable List View in android with groups and child both as text views, When i touch parent group it is showing different focused states , BUT CHILD DOES NOT SHOW THIS BEHAVIOR. I think it is problem with focus. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> **If you are using a Custom Expandable list Adapter:**

```
@SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    /*
    ....
    */

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

        return true; //this will be false by default. 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it , but still problem is there. I have custom xml selector states defined as background of text view. i just want to change child color when it is clicked

Comment: Without any code from you, i cannot recreate the whole thing to give a solution. Try to display a Toast or Log some text on click of the child item. If that works, it means your custom xml selector must also work for your child view. Another option is to remove custom selector and let the device default config reflect the changes in click event.

Comment: Clicks are working. 
This is child xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/menubackground" >
     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ChildName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: remove android:background="@drawable/menubackground" form the child layout and tell me what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add selector in ExpandableListView

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/button_hover"
```